# File not getting created - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I'm making a skype tool, and I'm creating the config file automatically, or at least that's what I think I am doing. The problem is just that for some reason the FileNotFoundException is fired because of some of my code is refering to the file which doesn't exist yet. So is visual basic checking for exceptions before firing code, or am I doing something wrong?
Here's my file creation code:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\BaconSkypeTool") Then

Else
  My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\BaconSkypeTool")
End If

If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Path) Then

Else
  Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(Path)
  Dim line1 As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes("This is the configuration file for BaconSkypeTool" & vbCrLf & "Please do not change anything in here if you don't know what you're doing." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Values below" & vbCrLf & "ChangeStatusInCall = True" & vbCrLf & "Status = Online" & vbCrLf & "Enable .cancel command = True")
  fs.Write(line1, 0, line1.Length)
  fs.Close()
End If
```

And here's the code that fires the exception:

```
skype.CurrentUserStatus = SKYPE4COMLib.TOnlineStatus.olsOnline
Dim text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\BaconSkypeTool\config.cfg")
Dim textAfterStatus As String = Nothing
Dim indexOfStatus = text.IndexOf("Status = ")
Dim text1 As String = Nothing
If indexOfStatus >= 0 Then
  textAfterStatus = text.Substring(indexOfStatus + "Status = ".Length)
  text1 = textAfterStatus.Split("Blacklist").First().Trim()
End If
```

The file creation is at the top of my file and therefore should be the first thing to be fired, but maybe that's just something I think.

Comment: Does the variable `Path` contain the full path `C:\BaconSkypeTool\config.cfg`, or does it only contain `C:\BaconSkypeTool`. You're creating the directory at the top, but it doesn't look like you've actually created the file yet. So you're attempting to read a nonexistent file if this is the case.

Comment: @Jdsfighter It contains the full path, and the code at the top is for creating the file, so of course I've not created the file at that point

Comment: In that case, I would separate your top code into its own function and use it as a validation. Wrap your read file code in an if block using the return value for validation to continue. From there, you can catch any errors that may arise.